# VSCode Emmet Extension Failing in .sol Files

Tags: solidity, hardhat, solc

Has anyone experienced the emmet extension terminate on them when in a Solidity file and then try and press tab and receive "command 'emmet.expandAbbreviation' not found"

I have no idea what to do to fix this. Please help!

I have expand on tab set to True for emmet in my settings.json

[extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)

Comment: Emmet supports solidity too? I thought it is just for HTML. Could you share the link to your extension?

Comment: sure! [extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)